# I get NullPointerException when Banner class is used (BlackBerry Advertising)

Tags: blackberry, nullpointerexception, ads, banner

I am integrating Banner Ads into my BB application.

Unfortunatelly, I am getting a strange NPE.

When I comment out the code to create/add Banner to my screen - I never get the NPE.

I'm running the default Strom 9530 BB simulator for JDE 4.7.0.

I tried to use debugger - however on debugger startup JDE asks me to provide '.debug' file for the net_rim_bbapi_adv_appXXXXX.cod which is not available on my side. So when I get the NPE I don't see  the "full picture".

Anyway, here is the call stack I see in the JDE debugger:

```
Calling Method                                                         Line

334:400
BrowserContentlmpl.requestSecondaryURL(String, boolean, boolean)               443
BrowserContentlmpl.addSecondaryURL(String, SecondaryURLNode, boolean)          404
HTMLBaseRenderer.makeBitmapField(
HTMLGenericElement, Border, String, int, int, int, int)                       6198
HTMLBaseRenderer.processElementlmg(HTMLGenericElement, boolean)               1992
HTMLBaseRenderer.processTag(int, HTMLGenericElement, boolean, boolean)        1114
HTMLBaseRenderer.handleOpenTag( HTMLGenericElement, boolean)                   970
RHTMLRenderer.handleTag(int)                                                  1620
RHTMLRenderer.parseData()                                                      602
HTMLBaseRenderer.finishProcessingData()                                        853
BrowserContentlmpl.finishLoading()                                             693
HTMLBrowserContent.finishLoading()                                             462
BrowserContentManager.handleNewContent()                                        92
BrowserContentManager.setContent(HttpConnection, RenderingApplication, Event)   56
334:30f
334:2235
```

The issue happens only if I push any other Screen over my Banner containing Screen while the Banner is not fully loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RIM developer **jreda** on BB support forum confirms the issue and says:

> We have confirmed that this is an
>   issue with the ad service library for
>   the 4.x OS. It will be fixed in the
>   next release but in the meantime there
>   shouldn't be any adverse effects on
>   your users as the exception should be
>   silently logged. If you are debugging,
>   the device will pause and you will
>   need to resume to move past the
>   exception but in normal operation the
>   user should not notice the an
>   exception has occurred.